# simple variance & standard deviation for a numbers array

Tags: php, standard-deviation, variance

I've been reading all about standard deviation and variance in PHP, found many examples online here and there, but still none of them gave me the same result as of the Excel.

Say I have:

```
  $array1 = array(5,46,37,21,8,55,1);
```

I just want the variance and standard deviation of these numbers within the array...

Any simple straight forward clue?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation.html

```
class SomeClass
{
    public $variance = 0.0;
    public $deviation = 0.0;

    public function run(array $array = [])
    {
        if (empty($array)) {
            echo "Passed array can't be empty and must contain only numbers.";
            die();
        }

        $this->variance = $this->getVariance($array);
        $this->deviation = $this->getStdDeviation($this->variance);
    }

    /**
    * Calculate variance.
     * Note: If no huge number of items we will not use "Sample" variance (but n items instead: n-1 items)
     *
     * @param array $arrayOfNumbers
     * @return float
     */
    private function getVariance(array $arrayOfNumbers)
    {
        $variance = 0.0;
        $totalElementsInArray = count($arrayOfNumbers);
        // Calc Mean.
        $averageValue = array_sum($arrayOfNumbers) / $totalElementsInArray;

        foreach ($arrayOfNumbers as $item) {
            $variance += pow(abs($item - $averageValue), 2);
        }

        return $variance;
    }

    /**
    * Simple deviation.
    * 
    * @param float $variance
    * @return float
    */
    private function getStdDeviation($variance)
    {
        return (float)sqrt($variance);
    }
}

$stat = new SomeClass;
$stat->run([5,46,37,21,8,55,1]);

echo "\n\nRESULTS:\n";
echo "\nVariance: " . $stat->variance;
echo "\nDeviation: " . $stat->deviation;
```

Comment: Add some descriprtion

Comment: @Bila I edited source and added complete class + link to one of good sources to learn statistics.
Note: I've not tested class yet, but I will when I will have more time.

Answer (score 0):

This step-wise procedure is copied from a Google Help Page, although I have done this myriad time.  I forget easily. To calculate the standard deviation of an array of numbers:

1. Work out the Mean (the simple average of the numbers)
2. Then for each number: subtract the Mean and square the result.
3. Then work out the mean of those squared differences.
4. Take the square root of that and we are done!

Also note: The standard deviation is simply the square root of the variance. ...
(So Step 3 is "The Variance" and Step 4 is "The Standard Deviation")

Here is a link that shows exactly how to do it in PHP.

[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-program-find-standard-deviation-array/][1]

Here is ***that code copied*** to this post:

To calculate the standard deviation, we have to first calculate the variance. The variance can be calculated as the sum of squares of differences between all numbers and means. Finally to get the standard deviation we will use the formula, √(variance/no_of_elements).

Below is the implementation in PHP to calculate the standard deviation:

```
<?php

    // function to calculate the standard deviation
    // of array elements
    function Stand_Deviation($arr)
    {
        $num_of_elements = count($arr);

        $variance = 0.0;

                // calculating mean using array_sum() method
        $average = array_sum($arr)/$num_of_elements;

        foreach($arr as $i)
        {
            // sum of squares of differences between 
                        // all numbers and means.
            $variance += pow(($i - $average), 2);
        }

        return (float)sqrt($variance/$num_of_elements);
    }

    // Input array
    $arr = array(2, 3, 5, 6, 7);

    print_r(Stand_Deviation($arr));

?>
```

Comment: I saw that actually before posting the question, but for some reason doesn't work with me, don't know why, keeps giving different number than Excel.. will try one more and see..

Comment: try adding the line "return $variance/$num_of_elements" (before the square root), because maybe you are getting the Variance (not the standard deviation) from Excel...  I mean, the math is simple - it's just an average of array values!  It can't be wrong.  There are other versions of statistics in Excel, but I know almost nothing about them, I'm not an Excel guy.  If I've made this worse, sorry for posting...

Comment: well, even-though, the variance here is not calculated in your given example which i saw online before, the variance is static variable = 0 then there is variance+= i mean how to test the variance of this array?

Comment: This explanation copied from: [link](https://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/science-fair/variance-and-standard-deviation)   I have done this many times in school (but I'm not in school now).

1) Subtract the mean from each value in the data. This gives you a measure of the distance of each value from the mean.
2) Square each of these distances (so that they are all positive values), and add all of the squares together.
3) Divide the sum of the squares by the number of values in the data set.
4) The standard deviation (σ) is simply the (positive) square root of the variance.

Comment: I primarily use Java, Javascript and HTML/CSS - but I have done enought PHP to read the above code.  The syntax is right, and it clearly finds the **(_usual_) mathematical definition** of Mean, Median, Variance/Standard-Deviation...  I know that financial people use Excel - and **_maybe your Excel Spreadsheet_** is misusing the term Mean, Median and Variance.  They are very simple terms in mathematics - and very clearly defined above, _both in the PHP code, and in the English Language Definition_ I have typed above! (Again, copied from Google, but I sure remember it from college!)

Comment: Try comparing the output from a calculator, or maybe JavaScript, Java or some other language to see who is getting "Variance" wrong...